# How to protect a symmetric key?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016, symmetric-key

When a symmetric key is [created](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-symmetric-key-transact-sql) we have the option to encrypted it by using at least one of the following: certificate, password, symmetric key, asymmetric key or EKM.

When a password is used, it it said that:

> When a symmetric key is encrypted with a password instead of a
>   certificate (or another key), the TRIPLE DES encryption algorithm is
>   used to encrypt the password. Because of this, keys that are created
>   with a strong encryption algorithm, such as AES, are themselves
>   secured by a weaker algorithm.

So, using password is not best way to protect it. I was not able to find any pros and cons for using the other techniques.

Can anyone tell is there are difference from security or performance matter or it is just a matter of choice?

Comment: Tangencial but if you have concerns someone cracking your passwords you will get a lot more secure option by using an asymetric "encryption" (salted slow hash) but I don't think SQL implemented slow hashes yet

Answer (score 1):

As you show in your question, the [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-symmetric-key-transact-sql#remarks) say:

> When a symmetric key is encrypted with a password instead of a certificate (or another key), the TRIPLE DES encryption algorithm is used to encrypt the password. Because of this, keys that are created with a strong encryption algorithm, such as AES, are themselves secured by a weaker algorithm.

This is a simple warning that a key protected by a password is weaker than the same key protected by a certificate.

So, in order to compromise the symmetric key, you need to know the password.  An attacker might obtain the password by cracking the 3-DES encryption; they would then have access to symmetric key, and by extension everything that is protected by that key.

The take-away is, don't use a password to protect a key if the data protected by the key is valuable.  Use a certificate to encrypt the symmetric key.